# Atom / Nuclide: How do I stop this pop up with the push pin from appearing?

Tags: atom-editor, nuclide-editor

I am not sure when this started but I am now getting this annoying pop up any time I hover over something. Whats it called and how to I prevent it from appearing?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

These are Flow type hints. You can disable them by opening the Nuclide Settings page with `alt-cmd-,` on OS X or `alt-ctrl-,` elsewhere (separate from the Atom settings, it's searchable so it's easier to find things). Then search for "flow" and uncheck the "Enable Type Hints" box.

[image: Screenshot of the "Enable Type Hints" setting]